# The sqlx library gives weird base64 encoded looking results

Tags: go

I am using this library from http://jmoiron.github.io/sqlx/ to do a query. Following the documentation led me to the code below.

```
func cities(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, _ httprouter.Params) error {
    var main string
    var secondary string
    var limit string
    queryParams := make(map[string]interface{})

    if k := r.PostFormValue("keyword"); k != "" {
        main = "city.name LIKE :keyword"
        queryParams["keyword"] = k + "%"
    }

    if sk := r.PostFormValue("secondaryKeyword"); sk != "" && sk != "null" {
        secondary = "OR city.name = :secondaryKeyword"
        queryParams["secondaryKeyword"] = sk
    }

    if mr := r.PostFormValue("maxResults"); mr != "" {
        limit = "LIMIT :maxResults"
        queryParams["maxResults"] = mr
    }

    if lr := r.PostFormValue("lastRequest"); lr != "" && lr == "1" {
        limit = ""
    }

    query := fmt.Sprintf(`
        SELECT
            city.geonameid AS cityId,
            city.name AS cityName,
            COALESCE(admin1.name_local, '') AS admin1Name,
            country.name AS countryName,
            CONCAT_WS(' ', city.name, city.asciiname, country.name) AS searchString
        FROM geonames_cities1000 AS city
            INNER JOIN geonames_countryinfo AS country
                ON city.iso_alpha2 = country.iso_alpha2
            LEFT OUTER JOIN geonames_admin1_codes_ascii as admin1
                ON admin1.code = CONCAT(city.iso_alpha2, '.', city.admin1_code)
        WHERE %s %s
        ORDER BY city.name ASC %s;
    `, main, secondary, limit)

    nstmt, err := sql.DB.PrepareNamed(query)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    rows, err := nstmt.Queryx(queryParams)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    results := []interface{}{}

    for rows.Next() {
        row := make(map[string]interface{})
        err := rows.MapScan(row)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        results = append(results, row)
    }

    b, err := json.Marshal(results)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    w.Write(b)
    return nil
}
```

Sending a POST request postman chrome plugin with these values:

```
keyword: "tron"
maxResults: 7
lastRequest: 0
```

gave this JSON output:

```
[
    {
        "admin1Name": "VXR0YXJhZGl0",
        "cityId": 1605268,
        "cityName": "VHJvbg==",
        "countryName": "VGhhaWxhbmQ=",
        "searchString": "VHJvbiBUcm9uIFRoYWlsYW5k"
    },
    {
        "admin1Name": "Q2FsYWJyaWE=",
        "cityId": 8949073,
        "cityName": "VHJvbmNh",
        "countryName": "SXRhbHk=",
        "searchString": "VHJvbmNhIFRyb25jYSBJdGFseQ=="
    },
    {
        "admin1Name": "QXJhZ29u",
        "cityId": 3107444,
        "cityName": "VHJvbmNow7Nu",
        "countryName": "U3BhaW4=",
        "searchString": "VHJvbmNow7NuIFRyb25jaG9uIFNwYWlu"
    },
    {
        "admin1Name": "UHVlYmxh",
        "cityId": 8859151,
        "cityName": "VHJvbmNvbmFs",
        "countryName": "TWV4aWNv",
        "searchString": "VHJvbmNvbmFsIFRyb25jb25hbCBNZXhpY28="
    },
    {
        "admin1Name": "U2NobGVzd2lnLUhvbHN0ZWlu",
        "cityId": 2821000,
        "cityName": "VHLDtm5kZWw=",
        "countryName": "R2VybWFueQ==",
        "searchString": "VHLDtm5kZWwgVHJvbmRlbCBHZXJtYW55"
    },
    {
        "admin1Name": "U8O4ci1UcsO4bmRlbGFn",
        "cityId": 3133880,
        "cityName": "VHJvbmRoZWlt",
        "countryName": "Tm9yd2F5",
        "searchString": "VHJvbmRoZWltIFRyb25kaGVpbSBOb3J3YXk="
    },
    {
        "admin1Name": "VG9uZ3Nh",
        "cityId": 1252408,
        "cityName": "VHJvbmdzYQ==",
        "countryName": "Qmh1dGFu",
        "searchString": "VHJvbmdzYSBUcm9uZ3NhIEJodXRhbg=="
    }
]
```

Why are the results like this? Putting the results in spew.Dump()
will give something like this (I'm just outputting one of the rows):

```
(map[string]interface {}) (len=5) {
  (string) (len=11) "countryName": ([]uint8) (len=6 cap=6) {
   00000000  4e 6f 72 77 61 79                                 |Norway|
  },
  (string) (len=12) "searchString": ([]uint8) (len=26 cap=26) {
   00000000  54 72 6f 6e 64 68 65 69  6d 20 54 72 6f 6e 64 68  |Trondheim Trondh|
   00000010  65 69 6d 20 4e 6f 72 77  61 79                    |eim Norway|
  },
  (string) (len=6) "cityId": (int64) 3133880,
  (string) (len=8) "cityName": ([]uint8) (len=9 cap=9) {
   00000000  54 72 6f 6e 64 68 65 69  6d                       |Trondheim|
  },
  (string) (len=10) "admin1Name": ([]uint8) (len=15 cap=15) {
   00000000  53 c3 b8 72 2d 54 72 c3  b8 6e 64 65 6c 61 67     |S..r-Tr..ndelag|
  }
```

What do I do wrong here?'

EDIT:

I tried doing as Elwinar suggested with structs instead. But something really weird is going on.

This code works:

```
type City struct {
    AdminName    string `json:"admin1Name"   db:"admin1Name"`
    CityID       int64  `json:"cityId"       db:"cityId"`
    CityName     string `json:"cityName"     db:"cityName"`
    CountryName  string `json:"countryName"  db:"countryName"`
    SearchString string `json:"searchString" db:"searchString"`
}
```

But this code does not work and outputs error "missing destination name cityId":

```
type City struct {
    CityId       int64  `json:"cityId"       db:"cityId"`
    CityName     string `json:"cityName"     db:"cityName"`
    Admin1Name   string `json:"admin1Name"   db:"admin1Name"`
    CountryName  string `json:"countryName"  db:"countryName"`
    SearchString string `json:"searchString" db:"searchString"`
}
```

What is the difference?

Solution: Must separate the tags with space key. Can not do spacing with tab key, and can not use commas to separate tags.

Comment: Which type is e.g. `countryName` in your database schema ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As `spew.Dump` tells you, the SQL driver returns `[]uint8` for textual column. In fact, it is equivalent to `[]byte`, which `json.Marshal` encode as base64 strings.

The simplest way to work around that is to scan your rows into a real struct (which sqlx does quite well with `StructScan`), which will have `string` fields so that `json.Marshal` will display them as you expect. You can control the name of both the SQL and JSON names of the field using tags, so your entity can have conventionnal names in every language…

Example:

```
type City struct {
    AdminName    string `json:"admin1Name"   sql:"admin1Name"`
    CityID       int64  `json:"cityId"       sql:"cityId"`
    CityName     string `json:"cityName"     sql:"cityName"`
    CountryName  string `json:"countryName"  sql:"countryName"`
    SearchString string `json:"searchString" sql:"searchString"`
}
```

Comment: I tried to do that but I keep getting "missing destination name cityId" error.

Comment: Ok it works now, I needed to change the sql tag to db tag!

Comment: Thanks. By the way do you know if I should defer rows.Close() and additional err = rows.Err() check at the end as emphasized here: http://go-database-sql.org/retrieving.html

Comment: I keep getting the "missing destination name cityId" error

Comment: This error occurs when the struct doesn't have a matching field for a result's coumn. So, double-check the tags (I can't remember if its `db` or `sql`, there is long time I used it) and the results names. The case matter…

Comment: I made an edit on the post, please check it. Your struct works, if I just replace sql with db, but when I do it does not work. The only difference is the admin name and ID instead if Id and the ordering of the struct properties..

Comment: I don't know exactly what change, but I would suggest opening another question so you can provide a fuller example without polluting this question (given that the question themselves are mostly unrelated).

Comment: In case you wondered I found out the issue. I can not have comma separated tags, I can only do spacing with the space key, I can't even tab.

Answer (score 3):

Package encoding/json will marshal `[]byte` slices base64 encoded (see http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal). So the problem is just in the output via `json.Marshal(results)`.

Somewhere your code calls a function which produces a `[]byte` which is nicely hidden in one of these `{}interface`s . Get rid of each of the empty interfaces, use strings where appropriate and the problem will either vanish or the solution will be obvious.

(Calling `json.Marshal` and outputting the result for debug purpose might not be a good idea, especially if you do not really know what you are actuall marshaling.)